# PagedDataSource not getting datasource

Tags: c#, datasource, icollection, entitycollection

I cannot get a `PagedDataSource` to use an IEnumerated collection of `EntityCollection` objects as a datasource.

The `PagedDataSource` accepts the collection as a datasource but then I can't use basic properties like `CurrentPageIndex` and `IsLastPage` etc.

My application breaks with the error `Cannot compute Count for a data source that does not implement ICollection.`

I tried doing

`ICollection<Location> listlocations = Company.Locations;`

but had no success.

What can I do?

Codesnippet

```
    protected void loadBuildings()
    {
        PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
        pds.DataSource = Company.Locations;
        pds.AllowPaging = true;
        pds.PageSize = Convert.ToInt16(ddlPageSize.SelectedValue);
        pds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
        lnkbtnNext.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;
        lnkbtnPrevious.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;

        buildingsDataList.DataSource = pds;
        buildingsDataList.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the option `AllowCustomPaging` and define my own pages because `EntityCollection` doesn't support the `ICollection` class.

I added the following code to define my pages/items

```
    pds.VirtualCount = Company.Locations.Count();
    pds.PageSize = 3;
    pds.AllowCustomPaging = true;
```

as well as some other code in my pagegeneration method

`for (int i = 0; i < (pds.VirtualCount/pds.PageSize);i++)`